# PHP encryption not compatible with .NET/C# decryption (AES-256/CBC)

Tags: c#, php, cryptography, aes

when I try to encrypt using openssl_encrypt PHP I get square spaces at the end decrypted data which is shown in attached image

My API response is getting failure due to getting extra characters during decryption done by .NET side..

How can i resolve this issue please help

C#

```
public static string Decrypt(String encryptedText, String VendorKey, String Token)
{
    var encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Decrypt(encryptedBytes, GetRijndaelManaged(VendorKey,Token)));
}

private static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] encryptedData, RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged)
{
    return rijndaelManaged.CreateDecryptor()
                .TransformFinalBlock(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
}

public static RijndaelManaged GetRijndaelManaged(String VendorKey, String Token)
{
    var keyBytes = new byte[32];
    var ivBytes = new byte[16];
            
    var secretKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(VendorKey + Token);
    Array.Copy(secretKeyBytes, keyBytes, Math.Min(keyBytes.Length, secretKeyBytes.Length));

    var ivKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(VendorKey);
    Array.Copy(ivKeyBytes, ivBytes, Math.Min(ivBytes.Length, ivKeyBytes.Length));

    return new RijndaelManaged
    {
       Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
       Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros,
       KeySize = 256, 
       BlockSize = 128, 
       Key = keyBytes,
       IV = ivKeyBytes
    };
}

public static string Encrypt(String plainText, String VendorKey, String Token)
{
    var plainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(plainBytes, GetRijndaelManaged(VendorKey, Token)));
}

private static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plainBytes, RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged)
{
    return rijndaelManaged.CreateEncryptor()
                .TransformFinalBlock(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
}

public static RijndaelManaged GetRijndaelManaged(String VendorKey, String Token)
{
    var keyBytes = new byte[32];
    var ivBytes = new byte[16];
            
    var secretKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(VendorKey + Token);
    Array.Copy(secretKeyBytes, keyBytes, Math.Min(keyBytes.Length, secretKeyBytes.Length));

    var ivKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(VendorKey);
    Array.Copy(ivKeyBytes, ivBytes, Math.Min(ivBytes.Length, ivKeyBytes.Length));

    return new RijndaelManaged
    {
       Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
       Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros,
       KeySize = 256, 
       BlockSize = 128, 
       Key = keyBytes,
       IV = ivKeyBytes
    };
}
```

So can help me to resolve this issue

[image]

Comment: Looks like a padding mode mismatch. Try PKCS7 and/or checking the settings on what's doing the encrypting.

Comment: Can u please eleborate?

Comment: For encryption you apply the default PKCS#7 padding, for decryption (btw, why is this commented out, the question refers to decryption after all?) you disable this with `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING`, so that the padding bytes are not removed at the end. Set the 4th parameter to `0` (as for encryption). Also, you Base64 encode twice during encryption, because `openssl_encrypt()` Base64 encodes by default. Therefore remove the *eplicit* `base64_encode()`. Then decryption works.

Comment: I removed that AND why this error come
 "error:0606508A:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:data not multiple of block length" string(216)

Comment: Not reproducible. Edit your question and post your most recent code throwing this exception.

Comment: Also post the C# code for decryption.

Comment: Sometime this error sometime it not come

Comment: @Topaco  c# code also added

Comment: Is the C# code reference code or can it be changed? If the C# code is the reference code, you need to adjust the padding in the PHP code when encrypting. The C# code uses Zero padding, so you have to disable the standard PKCS#7 padding with `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` in the PHP code and manually pad the plaintext with 0x00 values (since `openssl_encrypt()` does not support Zero padding). Note that `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` is a poor name and only disables the default PKCS#7 padding.

Comment: @Topaco can u give syntax how to used manually disabled the  PKCS#7
&&
No encrypted data get using OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING

Comment: @Topaco i used this code

function zeroPad($text, $bs) {
    $pad = $bs - strlen($text) % $bs;
    return ($pad < 32) ? $text .  str_repeat("\0", $pad) : $text;
}

Not work can u please check

Comment: In the PHP code you have 761288 (and not 761289 )! Can you provide the ciphertext that the .NET code expects for this VendorKey and token, or even better the C# encryption code?

Comment: @Topaco i added encryption code as well

Comment: Please see my answer.

Comment: This question does not have a clear, useful title.

Comment: @Topaco also do one thing in your answer  please change key and token or replaced with xxxx characters if possible so

Comment: Done, now dummy values are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the sample data you provided, encryption with the .NET code:

```cs
string vendorKey = "0123456789012345";
string token = "012345";
string pt = @"{""prospectNo"":""SL1000000"",""paymentRequestDateFrom"":""2020-05-28"",""paymentRequestDateTo"":""2020-06-02"",""merchantTransactionId"":""7"",""callerReferenceNo"":""3""}";
string ct = Encrypt(pt, vendorKey, token);
Console.WriteLine(ct);
```

returns the following ciphertext:

```
g163a7jXmZKjH1J3RjC7xkPn5+PJWY6wTX9BgxiTY8hkYjsqImlCuvXOtZgUrrfLnwLy1QGUk6iylc/sInV/XJ9sypJ93tCvjRoj4s4RWGKTqUk3bY31JTM6QuYVclw4zNvyq2WUBCc+EMGGYtn5dBAvqiYdTqrJJTae67EZfgc4Fw5ormmf0rCYXQ2mn7mc1Jdg8v2r3LK9FYiwLEbhOA==
```

The PHP code below:

```php
<?php
$cipher = "AES-256-CBC"; 

$array =  json_encode(array(
    "prospectNo"=> "SL1000000",
    "paymentRequestDateFrom"=>"2020-05-28",
    "paymentRequestDateTo"=>"2020-06-02",
    "merchantTransactionId"=> "7",
    "callerReferenceNo"=>"3"
    )
);

$token = "012345";
$vendorKey = "0123456789012345";
$key = substr(str_pad($vendorKey . $token, 32, "\0"), 0, 32);
$iv = substr(str_pad($vendorKey, 16, "\0"), 0, 16);

$encrypted_data = openssl_encrypt(zeroPad($array, 16), $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv); 
print($encrypted_data . "\n");

function zeroPad($text, $bs) { 
    $pad = ($bs - strlen($text) % $bs) % $bs; 
    return ($pad > 0) ? $text . str_repeat("\0", $pad) : $text; 
}
?>
```

gives the same ciphertext and is thus the PHP counterpart you are looking for, i.e. under the premise that the API can process the data encrypted by the .NET code, it must also process the data encrypted by the PHP code.

---

As expected, this ciphertext is decrypted into the correct plaintext by the .NET code. The hex encoded plaintext also reveals that the .NET code does *not* remove the padding bytes (note the 8 0x00 bytes at the end):

```cs
string vendorKey = "0123456789012345";
string token = "012345";
string ct = "g163a7jXmZKjH1J3RjC7xkPn5+PJWY6wTX9BgxiTY8hkYjsqImlCuvXOtZgUrrfLnwLy1QGUk6iylc/sInV/XJ9sypJ93tCvjRoj4s4RWGKTqUk3bY31JTM6QuYVclw4zNvyq2WUBCc+EMGGYtn5dBAvqiYdTqrJJTae67EZfgc4Fw5ormmf0rCYXQ2mn7mc1Jdg8v2r3LK9FYiwLEbhOA==";
string dt = Decrypt(ct, vendorKey, token);
Console.WriteLine("Plaintext:      " + dt);
Console.WriteLine("Plaintext, hex: " + Convert.ToHexString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dt)));
```

with the output:

```
Plaintext:      {"prospectNo":"SL1000000","paymentRequestDateFrom":"2020-05-28","paymentRequestDateTo":"2020-06-02","merchantTransactionId":"7","callerReferenceNo":"3"}
Plaintext, hex: 7B2270726F73706563744E6F223A22534C31303030303030222C227061796D656E74526571756573744461746546726F6D223A22323032302D30352D3238222C227061796D656E745265717565737444617465546F223A22323032302D30362D3032222C226D65726368616E745472616E73616374696F6E4964223A2237222C2263616C6C65725265666572656E63654E6F223A2233227D0000000000000000
```

---

The PHP code posted in this answer differs from your original PHP code essentially only in a more general derivation of `$key` and `$iv` (but this makes no difference for the `vendorKey` used here) and the padding. The original PHP code applied the default PKCS#7 padding used by `openssl_encrypt()`, while the current PHP code applies Zero padding.

Specifically, for the current plaintext, this means that the original PHP code padded with 0x0808080808080808, while the current PHP code pads with 0x0000000000000000. Since the .NET code does not remove the padding, the padding bytes are still present even when using the current PHP code (just with different values).